# emacs + latex + yasnippet: Why are newlines inserted after a snippet?

Tags: emacs, latex

Everytime I insert a snippet (with yasnippet) in a .tex document, I obtain a newline after the snippet. This is quite annoying for small snippets that are typically used in text style. How can I avoid that?

I read a bit about the problem (http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/issues/detail?id=115 or http://yasnippet.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/faq.html) but couldn't find a solution. Reproduce it as follows (I work with Aquamacs 2.3a on Mac OS X 10.6.8 with yasnippet version 0.6.1c):

1. Define ~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el to be:
   (require 'yasnippet)
   (yas/initialize)
   (yas/load-directory "~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/plugins/yasnippet-0.6.1c/snippets")
2. define the following snippet (call it "bm.yasnippet" [bm = boldmath]; the star * symbolizes where the cursor ends -- note that there is no newline after the snippet)

   ```
   # name: \bm{}{}
   # key: bm
   # --
   \bm{$1}*
   ```
3. restart Aquamacs and open a .tex file and type in bm + <kbd>Tab</kbd> [this should insert the snippet]
4. A newline is added after the snippet. This is quite inconvenient since `\bm{foo}` is typically used in text style, so for example in "The vector `\bm{x}` is not the null vector". A typical cause of this is that the snippet ends with a newline which is then inserted, too. However, I specifically obtain this behavior even the snippet does *not* end with a newline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't repro it with plain Emacs.  In fact, I had this exact issue, but my problem is I had `require-final-newline` set to *t*.  So Emacs was adding a newline at the end of my template.

My setup is a little more complicated but the solution for you is probably to set `mode-require-final-newline` to nil and restart Emacs.

To verify this is the problem, open up the template and check for the final newline.

Comment: Dear event_jr, thank you very much!!! I didn't know about these variables... I simply used "(setq-default mode-require-final-newline nil)" in my Preferences.el and it solved the problem completely :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answers in [Temporarly disable adding of newlines in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738897/temporarly-disable-adding-of-newlines-in-emacs/23739475), I'm using a function to only temporarily disable the adding of final newlines in the current buffer:

```
(defun disable-final-newline ()
    (interactive)
    (set (make-local-variable 'require-final-newline) nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason why u got a new line is that your snippet has space or tab at the end.
Ctrl+e and Ctrl+k to kill them will make it works, nearly 1 hour to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a few snippets, one of that was \frac{}{} which I use quite often.
The snippet version of frac that I use is not the one bundled with yasnippets.

The issue was that I edited some of the snippets in VIM and when you save the file, VIM automatically appends a newline to it.
To resolve it I had to remove the newline in a different editor e.g. emacs.