# Temporarly disable adding of newlines in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've enabled `require-final-newline`, because I usually want Emacs to add newlines to my files where it's missing. But there are some cases, where I *want* Emacs to *remove* the newline (like when editing a yasnippet that should not produce a newline, see [emacs + latex + yasnippet: Why are newlines inserted after a snippet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619640/emacs-latex-yasnippet-why-are-newlines-inserted-after-a-snippet)).

Is there a way to achieve this temporarly (like enabling a mode or something), without having to change `.emacs` and restarting Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what @eldrich mentioned, you can set its value locally in a given buffer.  Put something like this on a mode hook, to turn it off for a given mode:

```
(defun foo () (set (make-local-variable 'require-final-newline) nil))
(add-hook 'some-mode-hook 'foo)
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of setting it local to the buffer and not having to remember to re-enable it. I came up with a buffer-generic version: `(defun disable-final-newline () (interactive) (set (make-local-variable 'require-final-newline) nil))`

Answer (score 2):

Anything that is set in the `.emacs` file can be changed on the fly.  For variables such as `require-final-newline`, this just involves changing the variable.  For example, you could type the following code, then use `C-x e` to evaluate it.

```
(setq require-final-newline (not require-final-newline))
```

This could then be bound as a keyboard shortcut, if you so desire.

```
(defun toggle-final-newline
    (interactive)
    (setq require-final-newline (not require-final-newline)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c f") 'toggle-final-newline)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think It should be:

```
(defun toggle-final-newline ()
    (interactive)
    (setq require-final-newline (not require-final-newline)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c f") 'toggle-final-newline)
```

Comment: Please explain more -- why do you *think* it should be this? Answers should be more confident